# the problem with scanner.nextLine() in the for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, java.util.scanner

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Age: ");
    in.nextInt()
}
```

> I expect the output of:

Name: David Obama

Age: 14

Name: Ava Omidi

Age: 53

etc.

> but this is my output and only once nextLine() is used:

Name: David Obama

Age: 14

Name: Age:

Answer (score 1):

If you called nextInt or nextDouble you need to call scan.nextLine(); command immediately after that, to read any string properly.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Age: ");
    in.nextInt()

    //you need to make another call to nextLine() because of the Scanner object
    //will read the rest of the line where its previous read left off. 
    in.nextLine();
}
```